# What is the Si–N–C bond angle in silyl isothiocyanate?

Tags: molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

In silyl isothiocyanate, supposedly, the value of the bond angle $x$ is $180^\circ$.

[image: Structure of silyl isothiocyanate]

I don't know how to figure this out. There is a lone pair on nitrogen and two sigma bonds. Shouldn't it have sp<sup>2</sup>- or sp<sup>3</sup>-hybrid orbitals and thus $x$ be smaller than $180^\circ$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer that you are **supposed** to give is presumably something along the lines of "dπ–pπ" bonding between silicon and nitrogen. This essentially means that the lone pair of nitrogen is involved with backbonding into a silicon 3d orbital, leading to a linear geometry at nitrogen (i.e. the bond angle is 180°). This can be represented with the following resonance structures:

[image: supposed dπ-pπ bonding]

**To be very clear, this is very likely incorrect.** The extent of d-orbital involvement in main group compounds is usually tiny. If there is any backbonding, the acceptor orbital is probably a Si–H σ* orbital rather than a d-orbital (cf. [backbonding from transition metal to phosphine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/68704/16683)).

Electron diffraction studies of H<sub>3</sub>SiNCS show that the Si–N–C bond angle is actually 163.8°.<sup>1</sup> A computational study (TZVP + MP2 level of theory) found 165.91°.<sup>2</sup>. In fact, the linear structure above is not an energy minimum, but rather a *transition state* for the interconversion of the two energy minima:<sup>3</sup>

[image: conformers of H3SiNCS]

I don't actually know how one can predict this *a priori* without access to a computer, but clearly this system is not amenable to bond angle prediction with VSEPR theory, and invoking the so-called "Si–N dπ–pπ bonding" doesn't give the correct answer either.

---

*References*

1. Glidewell, C.; Robiette, A. G.; Sheldrick, G. M. Electron diffraction study of large amplitude vibrations in H<sub>3</sub>SiNCO and H<sub>3</sub>SiNCS. *Chem. Phys. Lett.* **1972,** *16* (3), 526–529. [DOI: 10.1016/0009-2614(72)80416-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(72)80416-0).
2. Palmer, M. H.; Nelson, A. D. The structures of the azido-, isocyanato- and isothiocyanato-derivatives of methane and silane and their derivatives. A comparison of ab initio with experimental results. *J. Mol. Struct.* **2004,** *689* (1–2), 161–173. [DOI: 10.1016/j.molstruc.2003.11.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molstruc.2003.11.008).
3. Palmer, M. H.; Guest, M. F. The methyl, silyl and germyl esters of the pseudo-halogen acids. A comparison of structural data from experimental and ab initio studies. *Chem. Phys. Lett.* **1992,** *196* (1–2), 183–190. [DOI: 10.1016/0009-2614(92)85951-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(92)85951-6).

Comment: Despite the bond angles being measurably less than $180°$, the assumption of $sp$ hybridization remains quite accurate. See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/174309/17175) with respect to the central atom in carbon suboxide.