# What is the CNC bond angle in methyl isothiocyanate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

According to VSEPR theory, for $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridisation the bond angle is approximately $120^\circ$. In $\ce{H3CNCS}$, the nitrogen has one lone pair. As lone-pair-bond-pair repulsion is greater than bond-pair-bond-pair repulsion, the bond angle of $\ce{CNC}$ should be less than $120^\circ$,  but it is actually greater. How can this be rationalised?

Comment: I took a liberty to correct formatting, notations and added compound's name. But where did you find a C−N−C in $\ce{\ce{CH3CNS}}?$ What angle are you talking about, exactly? Have you seen https://doi.org/10.1071/CH10303, especially [its SI available for free](https://www.publish.csiro.au/ch/acc/CH10303/CH10303_AC.pdf)?

Comment: Actually a typing mistake. It would be CH3NCS. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No prob, I corrected the name and bond order accordingly. I'm pretty sure answers from [Bond angle in CH3NCO](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95200/bond-angle-in-ch3nco) would apply here as well: partial delocalization of the lone pair on N into a π orbital on C. This effect is even more pronounced in silyl isothiocyanate, which is almost linear.

Comment: @andselisk the answers aren't really good though. To all who are tempted, I would let this question open for the time being.

Comment: Related: [What is the Si–N–C bond angle in silyl isothiocyanate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81974/16683)

Answer (score 8):

I have just answered [What is the CNC bond angle in methyl isocyanate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/136284/4945) Pretty much everything written there also applies to methyl isothiocyanate, just a bit more extreme.

Here is the structure calculated on the RI-BP86/def2-SVP level of theory:

[image: molecular structure methyl isothiocyanate]

The bond angle is $\angle(\ce{CNC}) = 156^\circ$, so we expect a much larger contribution of the right side in the following resonance description:
$$\ce{H3C-N=C=S <-> H3C-N^+\bond{3}C-S^-}$$

Reasons for this are not trivial, but that would exceed the scope of this answer.

**TL;DR** From VSEPR we would expect a trigonal coordination and a $120^\circ$ angle. Refining with resonance, we'll expect a widening of the bond angle. Everything beyond that  needs much more involved models.

Comment: Similar to an other comment, not about methyl isothiocyanates, but $\ce{R-N=C=S}$ there are at least these 15 entries in the COD with coordinates to compare with: http://www.crystallography.net/cod/7116329.html and (just substitute the numbers), COD7116328, 7116327, 7116326, 7116325, 7103098, 4117347, 4108942, 4108356, 4075734, 4024672, 4024671, 2234166, 2233483, and 2214501.