Confusion in comparing contribution of resonance structures in Hydrazoic acid
Given below is the resonance hybrid of $\ce{HN3}$(Hydrazoic acid)

And these are the resonance structures below:

If the second resonance structure had contributed more, then the two bond lengths would be equal in resonance hybrid, but it is not so. It implies that the first resonance structure contributes more towards real structure based on bond lengths and 109-degree bond angle (i.e. sp3 N) data.
How can we tell which resonance structure among the two will contribute more towards the real structure (i.e. the resonance hybrid) without any experimental data?
References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazoic_acid

Singh K. 1954The structure of hydrazoic acidProc. R. Soc. Lond. A225519–534. DOI:https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1954.0220

JD Lee adapted version (JEE Mains and Advanced) By Sudarshan Guha



related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/what-is-the-si-n-c-bond-angle-in-silyl-isothiocyanate https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95200/what-is-the-cnc-bond-angle-in-methyl-isocyanate

How can one tell? Using computational chemistry software.

@Mithoron So, we can't comment anything without software right?

This answer may help: chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/127340/112070
